# Windows 8 install turned my ext4 partition into unallocated space. How do I recover it?

Tags: partitioning, windows-8, live-usb, data-recovery, ext4

[image]

The unallocated space in sda2 is supposed to be an ext4 partition with my ubuntu install in it. How do I recover this from a live CD so I can back up my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot a live system, install testdisk, launch it, choose "Intel", choose "recover partition".

Comment: Worked. You missed a step though, which is "Write" if you want to recover it.